# Facebook Wall Feed to Website - Jquery / not PHP

Tags: jquery, facebook

I am trying to pull the activity from my Facebook Page Wall, including images to my website. However, with the standard Activity Plugin , shows everything (including my friends, but I only want to limit it to my pages posting).

Is there any way to do this in a Jquery way? Bar PHP.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '385846108120057', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML      
    });          

   FB.api(
  {
    method: 'fql.query',
     query: 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid=me()'
  });

  function(response) {
    alert('Your name is ' + response[0].name);
  });

 FB.api(
  {
    method: 'fql.query',
     query: 'SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message, attachment 
        FROM stream 
        WHERE source_id = '158904890800614', 
        AND actor_id = '158904890800614'; 
  }); 

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JavaScript SDK to make an FQL Query](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)(scroll down to the "API Calls" header) to the [stream table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/). This will return a JSON object that you should be able to parse and display easily using jQuery.

Here is a sample query to get you started:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message, attachment 
  FROM stream 
  WHERE source_id = 'PAGE_ID' 
    AND actor_id = 'PAGE_ID'
```

The `source_id` in the WHERE statement above limits the results to just posts on your page's wall, and the `actor_id` limits the results to just those made by your page.

Comment: Hi Cpilko - thanks for the comments - I will give it a shot. Much appreciated.

Comment: Heya - I am still having issues inserting the query. I have the Javascript SDK inserted - but where should I include the FQL Query?

Comment: See the "API Calls" heading on the JavaScript SDK Documentation page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: Hello Cpilko - hm I think I could be completely missing the boat... I posted my codes in the original question.

Comment: You don't have a response handler for your second API call like you do for your first, so you have the data, but you're not doing anything to display it.

Comment: Hello Cpilko - thanks again for the help.. much appreciated... yes I can see the data being pulled when I try it with the FQL Query in the Facebook developer site - will figure out how to display it. Thanks again!

Comment: Hello Cpilko - I still have problems displaying the information - any prompters will be much appreciated- Thank you so much for the help.